# Show that the linear estimator $L = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kX_k$ is consistent

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this problem on which I am stuck and dont know how to continue. The problem is as follows:

> "Let $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ be a sample with mean $\mu$ and variance
>   $\sigma^2$ and consider the linear estimator $ \displaystyle L_n =
> \> \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kX_k$
>
> where the $a_k$ are nonnegative and sum to 1. (a) Show that $L$ is
>   unbiased, (b) show that $L$ is consistent."

So, part (a) was pretty straight forward. It is part (b) I'm struggling with.

I have this proposition in my text book that says that if $Var(L) \longrightarrow 0$ as $n \longrightarrow \infty$ then $L$ is consistent. The proof makes use of the Chebyshev inequality.

So, my attempt goes like this:

$Var(L) = Var(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kX_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}Var(a_kX_k)$ because of the individual samples independence. Moreover,

$Var(L) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}Var(a_kX_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2Var(X_k) = \sigma^2\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2$

and now I dont know how to continue. I dont know how $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2$ behaves as $n \longrightarrow \infty$. All I know is that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k = 1$, and obviously this should be enough to solve the problem. I dont see however how I can use this in my attempted solution above.

I was hoping someone could give me a hint of how to continue from here.

Thanks!

Comment: You are completely wright. Say, if $a_1=1$ and $a_k=0$ for $k>1$ then $L=X_1$ does not converge to $\mu$.

Comment: The $a_k$ are themselves (identically distributed) random variables, and $\mathbb E[a_1]<1$ for $n>1$.

Comment: How do you know that the $a_k$'s are random variables?